# Php How to split a string containing special characters

Tags: php

Hello I have a string as

```
$str = "[10-1],[20-2],[30-3],";
```

this I want to split int two arrays as-

```
Array1
(
   [0] => 10
   [1] => 20
   [2] => 30
)

Array2
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 2
   [2] => 3
)
```

How it can be done? also my variable **$str**  is varying depending upon values..

Thanks..

Comment: The structure is always the same? If yes split on , then on -

Comment: regex matching \[[0-9]+[-][0-9+\]] :?

Comment: Yes structure is always same as [val,val],[val,val],[val,val], so on..

Comment: well if u put `{` and `}` arround it, u can use it as a json array with `json_decode()` :X - why the heck are there so many answers with explode? thats a simple regex like the one answer down there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split it using regex:

```
$str = "[10-1],[20-2],[30-3],";

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\[(\d+)-(\d+)\],/', $str, $matches);
```

If you `unset($matches[0]);` the remaining is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: This is brilliant. Better than my answer.

Comment: I know its very long. but, this one is really brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `explode()`. Theres almost certainly a better way, but its never let me down.

```
$array1 = [];
$array2 = [];
$str = "[10-1],[20-2],[30-3]";
$split = explode ('[', $str);
foreach ($split as $item) {
    $array = explode (']', $item);
    $array = explode('-', $array[0]);
    $array1[] = $array[1];
    $array2[] = $array[0];
}
```

Comment: Wow you just put an untested answer here! Seems to be high quality? (BTW: You forgot a `$` sgin)

Comment: Wow thanks @Rizier123 for you comment. I can rest easy now. Phew!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
$str = "[10-1],[20-2],[30-3],";

$str = str_replace(array("[","]"),"",$str);

$parts = explode(",",$str);

$arr1 = [];
$arr2 = [];
foreach($parts as $part){
    if($part){
        $arr_parts = explode("-",$part);
        $arr1[] = $arr_parts[0];
        $arr2[] = $arr_parts[1];
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arr1,$arr2);
```

Output is:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "30"
}
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
}
```

Comment: Good answer. BTW you can put like `is_array($part)` to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at it, I'd probably add $str = str_replace(array("[","]"),"",$str); underneath the original string rather than where it is at the moment.

Comment: Thank you so much... for the easy and right answer in very less time... @H2ONOCK

Comment: No worries, I've just made a quick amend. I have to be honest though, I prefer @axiac's answer.

Comment: `$arr1 = []; $arr2 = [];` I'm not really sure if this works in php. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Aditya it should work, but i preffer the oldschoolisch `$arr = array();`

Comment: @H2ONOCK Are you serious brother about this `$arr1 = [];` ?

Comment: As far as I know you can not declare array like `$arr1 = [];` this in PHP

Comment: Since PHP 5.4 arrays can be created using [] shorthand. Please read http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

'As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].' can also be seen in the arrays documentation http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Those who down-voted on the basis that you didn't know that arrays can be defined using [] hang your heads in shame! lol.

Answer (score 0):

Based on:

```
$str = "[10-1],[10-1],[30-3],";

$val = explode(",",$str); //Now we got an array similar to:Array ( [0] => [10-1] [1] => [10-1] [2] => [30-3])
$exitArray1 = array();
$exitArray2 = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count ($val); $i++){
 if(strlen($val[$i]) >0){
  $val[$i] = substr($val[$i],0,-1); //got [10-1
  $val[$i] = substr($val[$i],1); // got 10-1
  $temp = explode("-",);// Split on -
  $exitArray1[] = $temp[0]; //put 10 in first array
  $exitArray2[] = $temp[1]; //put 1 in second array
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution. But usng regex is the best bet:

```
<?php
$str = "[10-1],[20-2],[30-3]";
$arr = explode(',',$str);
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $val = trim($val,'[]');
    $temp = explode('-', $val);
    $array1[] = $temp[0];
    $array2[] = $temp[1];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 30
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Comment: every time in the loop using explode and *trim? u can replace the `[]` before the first `explode()`...